# identifying OTU interactions / hubs

Tags: microbiome, metagenomics

I would like to know how can i run a network analysis for identifying major OTUs hubs. I wish to build a network of co-occurring OTUs found in different soils samples.
I've started going through the VEGAN R package but i'm not sure it's what i'm looking for.
any recommendations network analysis packages ?
thank you!

Comment: Can you better define "major OTU hubs"?  Are you attempting to build a network of co-occurring OTUs and observe groupings?  Please [revise](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) your question.

Comment: can you tell us what your starting data look like? raw reads? count tables?

Answer (score 3):

I am going to assume you have a count table that you are starting with. Every tool you decide to use is going to have its own respective instructions so let me get you pointed in a direction to find one that works for you.

I wrote a simple [R package](https://github.com/jtclaypool/microbiome) for my lab awhile back but there are much better ways to put together Co-occurrence networks (in no particular order):

- [SparCC](https://bitbucket.org/yonatanf/sparcc/src/default/)
- [CoNet](http://psbweb05.psb.ugent.be/conet/)
- [MENA](http://129.15.40.240/mena/)
- [Spiec-Easi](https://github.com/zdk123/SpiecEasi)
- [MDiNE](https://github.com/kevinmcgregor/mdine)

Now speaking specifically about "hubs", "connectors", and other keystone organisms, I would recommend reading more about what they are and how they were developed. Again, I have a brief [summary here](https://github.com/jtclaypool/microbiome#keystone-microbes) but the original "hub" came from a paper on [bee pollination networks](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2148393/)